# DiskLruCache - IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, caching

I'm developing an Android app where I'm fetching a few images/videos from a server. I want to cache the info downloaded on disk but when I'm trying to put a new data to cache a error occurs and I don't know why because the key seems to be ok.
Here's the stack trace:

```
    06-03 18:27:38.942: E/AndroidRuntime(10893): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: keys must match regex [a-z0-9_-]{1,64}: "mYUb5gz5gx"
06-03 18:27:38.942: E/AndroidRuntime(10893):    at com.jakewharton.DiskLruCache.validateKey(DiskLruCache.java:633)
06-03 18:27:38.942: E/AndroidRuntime(10893):    at com.jakewharton.DiskLruCache.edit(DiskLruCache.java:421)
06-03 18:27:38.942: E/AndroidRuntime(10893):    at com.jakewharton.DiskLruCache.edit(DiskLruCache.java:416)
06-03 18:27:38.942: E/AndroidRuntime(10893):    at com.licenta.mementoapp.utils.DiskLruImageCache.put(DiskLruImageCache.java:69)
06-03 18:27:38.942: E/AndroidRuntime(10893):    at com.licenta.mementoapp.datafragments.PhotosFragment$1$1.done(PhotosFragment.java:92)
```

Doesn't the key ="mYUb5gz5gx" match the regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Your key contains capital letters. Only lowercase is allowed!

Comment: By the way I noticed the nice Stracktrace, which completely explains everything. You don't need to look at the code to find out, what's going wrong.

Comment: The problem was that I couldn't understand why the key didn't match the regex. I wasn't paying attention what the regex was!

Comment: No, the comment shouldn't be offending. I also needed to look twice. I'm also used to using uppercase and lowercase the same time.

Comment: I also wanted to ask you - is there a way to iterate over a DiskLruCache - to get all the keys for example?

Comment: No, I didn't see any method. But you could easily extend the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use MD5 tools to be a MD5code like this:

```
public static String hashKeyForDisk(String key) {
    String cacheKey;
    try {
        final MessageDigest mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        mDigest.update(key.getBytes());
        cacheKey = bytesToHexString(mDigest.digest());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        cacheKey = String.valueOf(key.hashCode());
    }
    return cacheKey;
}

private static String bytesToHexString(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & bytes[i]);
        if (hex.length() == 1) {
            sb.append('0');
        }
        sb.append(hex);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```